# Novacode Docx Create Image from Bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office, docx

## Background

My project is urgent and requires that I iterate a large XML file and return Base64 encoded images.

Each image must be inserted into an MS Word doc, and I am using the [DocX](http://docx.codeplex.com/) library for that.

I am converting the Base64 strings to bitmap with no problem.

## Problem

For the life of me, I can't seem to get the bitmaps into a *Novacode.Image* object which can then be inserted to the document.  NOTE: I already know how to convert to System.Drawing.Image format.  It is Novacode.Image format (DocX) that is giving me grief.

If I try to convert a la `(Novacode.Image)somebitmap;` I get `Can not cast expression of type Image to Bitmap`.  If I try to initialize a new `Novacode.Image` object I get `Can not access internal constructor Image here`.

Using C#, .NET 4, Forms App, lots of coffee.

## Question

Only Novacode.Image objects can be inserted into the MS Word doc via the library, so how the heck do I get my bitmap in there??

I am bleary-eyed at this point so perhaps I am just missing something simple.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use the `DocX.AddImage()` method to create a `Novacode.Image` object.

Follow these 5 steps to add a image to a word document:

1. Save your picture into a memory stream.
2. Create the `Novacode.Image` object by calling `AddImage()` method.
3. Create a picture by calling `CreatePicture()` on the `Novacode.Image` object created in step 2.
4. Set the shape of the picture (if needed).
5. Insert your picture into a pragraph.

The sample below shows how to insert a image into a word document:

```
using (DocX doc = DocX.Create(@"Example.docx"))
{
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    System.Drawing.Image myImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"test.jpg");

    myImg.Save(ms, myImg.RawFormat);  // Save your picture in a memory stream.
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);                    

    Novacode.Image img = doc.AddImage(ms); // Create image.

    Paragraph p = doc.InsertParagraph("Hello", false);

    Picture pic1 = img.CreatePicture();     // Create picture.
    pic1.SetPictureShape(BasicShapes.cube); // Set picture shape (if needed)

    p.InsertPicture(pic1, 0); // Insert picture into paragraph.

    doc.Save();
  }
}
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Hans, thanks for the help, but this still gave me trouble.  Particularly, ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);, threw an error stating that the stream was closed.  Also, I got errors on the .createPicture method.  I am thinking that I either have a bad DLL, or a bug in outside code.  Either way, I solved my problem by just using regular Word Interop methods.  I would like to take some time before selecting your answer as correct to be sure that the errors are on my side so that I don't mislead anyone.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Hans and Martin, I was able to use this as a basis for ensuring large image files (photos) are always sized to fit on the page. The max width and max height can be changed depending on your page size.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    System.Drawing.Image myImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imageDirectory + i.FileName);

    double xScale = 1;
    double yScale = 1;

    double maxWidthInches = 6.1; // Max width to fit on a page
    double maxHeightInches = 8.66; // Max height to fit on a page

    // Normalise the Horizontal and Vertical scale for different resolutions
    double hScale = ((double)96 / myImg.HorizontalResolution);
    double vScale = ((double)96 / myImg.VerticalResolution);

    // Scaling required to fit in x direction
    double imageWidthInches = myImg.Width / myImg.HorizontalResolution; // in inches using DPI
    if (imageWidthInches > maxWidthInches)
        xScale = maxWidthInches / imageWidthInches * hScale;

    // Scaling required to fit in y direction
    double imageHeightInches = myImg.Height / myImg.VerticalResolution;
    if (imageHeightInches > maxHeightInches)
        yScale = maxHeightInches / imageHeightInches * vScale;

    double finalScale = Math.Min(xScale, yScale); // Use the smallest of the two scales to ensure the picture will fit in both directions

    myImg.Save(ms, myImg.RawFormat); // Save your picture in a memory stream.
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    Novacode.Image img = document.AddImage(ms); // Create image.
    Paragraph p = document.InsertParagraph();
    Picture pic = img.CreatePicture(); // Create picture.

    //Apply final scale to height & width
    double width = Math.Round((double)myImg.Width * finalScale);
    double height = Math.Round((double)myImg.Height * finalScale);

    pic.Width = (int)(width);
    pic.Height = (int)(height);

    p.InsertPicture(pic); // Insert picture into paragraph.
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, would it not be easier to just use doc.PageWidth and doc.PageHeight, along the lines of:
`float scale = new[] { 1, picture.Width / doc.PageWidth, picture.Height / doc.PageHeight }.Max();
picture.Height = (int)(picture.Height / scale);
picture.Width = (int)(picture.Width / scale);`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Hans. I had an Issue where the Image is inserted at the wrong size based on the DPI so I used this to scale the image based on DPI, 96 dpi seemed to be the basis of the scaled image in word:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    System.Drawing.Image myImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path);

                    //Calculate Horizontal and Vertical scale
                    float Hscale = ((float)96 / myImg.HorizontalResolution); 
                    float Vscale = ((float)96 / myImg.VerticalResolution );

                    myImg.Save(ms, myImg.RawFormat);  // Save your picture in a memory stream.
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    Novacode.Image img = proposal.AddImage(ms); // Create image.
                    Picture pic1 = img.CreatePicture();     // Create picture.

                    //Apply scale to height & width
                    pic1.Height = (int)(myImg.Height * Hscale);
                    pic1.Width = (int)(myImg.Width * Vscale);

                    a.InsertPicture(pic1, 0); // Insert picture into paragraph.
                }
```