# Exporting HTML to word (with images)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ms-word

I am creating a database of test questions for teachers to use when creating new tests. For this, I need to store the questions somewhere (in a database or in a file system). This has to be done in a way that the teachers can access the questions through an online system in which they can see the questions, answers and info and alo filter the questions. After they have been chosen, there needs to be an option for the user to export the chosen questions to word so that he may use it as a test or something of the like.

My main question is, how can I store these test questions? Most of them have pictures on them, so storing the text is not enough. Also, there may be many pictures in different places. I initially thought of storing the question in HTML, with links to the pictures and tags for formating. But searching the web, I couldn't find something to efficiently convert the HTML do word that maintains formatting and inserts the picture into the word document. Can anybody help me in this front?

I am planning to make the question interface in ASP.NET using C#

(Apologies if the question is poorly written!)

Comment: You just need to find a library that generate Word documents, such as [DocX](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660478/Csharp-Create-and-Manipulate-Word-Documents-Progra). Note that since you are in an ASP.NET environment you should **not** use any Office COM Interop libraries.

Comment: By the way, images are just 0's and 1's. And you can convert them to a shorter format such as Base64. Then you can use those Base64 strings directly in HTML documents (it's called a Data URI). Scott Hanselman mentions it [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToDisplayAQRCodeInASPNETAndWPF.aspx). Some formats such as [vCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vcard) and [MTHML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mhtml) use that (though I'm not saying it's necessarily appropriate in this case).

Comment: I've worked a little bit with these kinds of libraries (more with excel though) and I think my main concern is inserting the images into the word document. In HTML I will have a link to the image, but how would I insert that image into the .doc file?

Comment: It's not a `.doc`. It's a `.docx`. You need to understand the difference between those if you're going to be creating them. Most libraries that allow you to insert images into documents well accept a byte array or file name. You'll have to look it up for the library you settle on. If you pick DocX, that already has an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807858/novacode-docx-create-image-from-bitmap).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For HTML to docx (as opposed to legacy binary .doc), you can try:

- http://htmltodocx.codeplex.com/
- http://www.nuget.org/packages/docx4j-ImportXHTML.NET/ (disclosure: my project)
- https://html2openxml.codeplex.com/